Using Aws Cloudformation and EventBridge how do I delete a DMS Replication Instance after its specific Replication Task has Finished?
I'm trying to schedule the deletion of a DMS Replication Instance whenever its ReplicationTask is "finished". I have a working Cloudformation template to create the Replication Instance and Replication Task. I have a Lambda function to delete the stack. I'm now trying to trigger the Lambda function with an Eventbridge event pattern. However DMS only logs a portion of the ReplicationTask ARN, it doesn't log the ReplicationTaskIdentifier (friendly name) or tags. I'm guessing I need to use an intrinsic function to get the ARN of the Replication Task and insert it into an event pattern. How can I do this, or this there a better way to accomplish this?
Here's what I tried for the Event Pattern using Fn::GetAtt for the ARN of the ReplicationTask, along with Lambda function creation-
EventBridgeRule:
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
Name: cfstst2-dms-repkill
EventPattern: >-
{"source":["aws.dms"],"detail":{"eventSource":["dms.amazonaws.com"],"detailMessage":[{"wildcard":"FINISHED"}],"resources":[{"Fn::GetAtt": ["cftst2-test, Arn"]}]}
State: ENABLED
EventBusName: default
Targets:
- Id: Id02e6f6d0-0f0c-4475-8c92-32a9faf7956f
Arn:
Fn::Sub: >-
arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:del-dms-repstack
Parameters: {}

Have you considered utilizing the DMS ReplicationTask event messages and publish them on a SNS topic rather than relying on EventBridge ? When you create event subscription in DMS, there is an option to select which replication task you want and also which SNS you want to publish on. The same lambda can subscribe to the SNS topic  to execute your custom logic.
